# How to config msdtc remote coordinator host name using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, msdtc

I'm trying to config msdtc remote coordinator host name on 17 web servers using powershell which is part of our deployment script. But I couldn't figure out how. i'm able to do it manually though using comexp.msc

The following is similar question asked by someone else, but the replay marked as answer doesn't make sense to me at all.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/571daa14-8180-4c79-a9de-80c628b38539#a08504e4-42cc-4de5-9262-76b3f2296536

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of command lets to actually help you set up MSDTC in powershell .Take a look at the [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh829474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and let me know if you have any questions, I will try get back to you asap.

Think this is the [one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128015%28v=vs.85%29) you might want to use to set the default transactions coordinator.

Comment: the answer above only work on powershell v3 on a Windows 2012 server. Is there a way to do in in Powershell V2 ?